# java syntax file difference between windows and linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, file, tomcat

I am trying to access a file in linux. I have previously read the file from Windows. Where I did something like this:

```
import java.io.File;

public static File readFile = new File("D:\\test.w3");
```

**This is probably a very silly question but how do I access that same file in the home directory or a sub folder?**

```
public static File readFile = new File("//home//test.w3");
```

I'm getting the old 404 from Apache Tomcat 9.0.6
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

I might have located the main problem.
But i do not know how to resolve it.
In eclipse when selecting the right server as I seem to have run the wrong one I get the following error:

[Tomcat server launch problem in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtoB9.png)

Any ideas where to begin the journey?
It is like if Eclipse reserves those ports and then refuses to disclose the rest. I have tried to change the port names but I get the same error with the new ports.

Comment: Why are you using double forward slashes?

Comment: one of my old java books uses double slashes for windows syntax. just assuming that it is the same in linux. Tried with single slash but that did not do a difference.

Comment: Backslash in a string literal "..." must be doubled, escaped, as backslash is used for escape sequences, `\n` is a linefeed character and so on. Slash not.

Answer (score 1):

Good news, the `File` constructor has a form that can help. And there's a `System.property` that maps to the HOME (that works across platforms)!

```
public static File readFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "test.w3");
```

It's also worth noting that you can use `/` as a path separator on both *nix and Windows systems. There's also [`File.separator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) if you want to manually build paths.

Comment: so if I want to have it somewhere in /opt/ where I have tomcat how would that look like? Just trying to figure out how it works in Linux...

Comment: @rageext You said home, but `File tc = new File("/opt/apache-tomcat-whatever");` and then if you wanted some sub-folder of that, `File tcBin = new File(tc, "bin");` etc - works the same way in Windows. Windows adds drive letters. But Java supports *nix style paths on Windows.

Comment: I'm still having trouble with all the solutions I've recieved. Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists. Could it be some kind of setting that I've overlooked in linux. Using Centos.

Comment: Origin server? Edit your question and include the output of `mount`. Exactly what path are you trying to access? You've said home folder and you've said something under "/opt". You should be able to access anything under your own home folder. If it's somewhere else, then you may not have permission (there are file permissions) to see it.

Comment: As I'm running eclipse oxygen on Centos7, Apache Tomcat 9.0.6 which is located in /opt/ folder that runs in god mode. Normally the webapps folder under tomcat is where you run all the pages now I think eclipse has set it to run in the eclipse-workspace under the home folder. I just want to access the file from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
String path = java.nio.file.FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("").toAbsolutePath().toString(); // If the path is similar with project location, else replace with your path.
String fileName = "test.w3";

public static File readFile = new File(path + "/" + fileName);
```

On `Linux` you should use `/` instead of `\\` from `Windows`.

Comment: just a follow up question on this solution. In what library is FileSystems?

Comment: You can find in `java.nio.file.FileSystems`. I updated the answer, my omission.